# Subsetting, Matrices

Tags: r

I am super new to R and currently playing with the "diamond" dataset.

I am trying to return the row corresponding to the lowest, mean and largest prices and put everything in a 10 by 4 matrix. Please explain an easier way of doing this if possible.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)


min(diamonds$price) 
mean(diamonds$price)
max(diamonds$price) # this one gives me the wrong val!

M<-matrix(1:cols, nrow = 1, ncol = cols)
colnames(M)<-c("carat","cut" , "color" , "clarity", "depth" , "table" , "price" ,  "x" , "y" ,"z")

# Here I need to add the rows corresponding to the min,mean,max to this matrix.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matrix and dataframes are different in R. `diamonds` is a dataframe it is better and easy to process if you keep it as dataframe only.

`summary(diamonds)` gives you some nice summary stats for each column.

If you want to apply specific functions to columns using `dplyr`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric),list(min = min, max = max, mean = mean))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
                      names_to = c('col', '.value'), 
                      names_sep = '_') 

# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  col     min      max     mean
#  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 carat   0.2     5.01    0.798
#2 depth  43      79      61.7  
#3 table  43      95      57.5  
#4 price 326   18823    3933.   
#5 x       0      10.7     5.73 
#6 y       0      58.9     5.73 
#7 z       0      31.8     3.54
```

Note that I applied these functions only to numeric columns since `cut`, `color`, `clarity` are `factor` columns.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to select the rows in the `diamonds` data frame corresponding to the mean, minimum, and maximum of price, this is easily accomplished with a combination of the `$` and `[` forms of the extract operator in Base R.

Note that this will return a data frame with 3 rows, not 4, because there are two rows at the minimum price, no rows at the mean price, and one row at the maximum price.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

diamonds[diamonds$price %in% c(min(diamonds$price),mean(diamonds$price),max(diamonds$price)),]
```

...and the output:

```
  carat cut     color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl> <ord>   <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23 Ideal   E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2  0.21 Premium E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3  2.29 Premium I     VS2      60.8    60 18823  8.5   8.47  5.16
```

A solution with `dplyr` uses `filter()` as follows.

```
# dplyr solution
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% filter(price %in% c(min(price),mean(price),max(price)))
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  carat cut     color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl> <ord>   <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23 Ideal   E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2  0.21 Premium E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3  2.29 Premium I     VS2      60.8    60 18823  8.5   8.47  5.16
>
```

Comment: @Achilles You can accept only one answer for every post. Click on check mark on left of this answer to accept this answer.

Comment: @Achilles - you can upvote more than one answer, however.

Comment: @LenGreski Due to low reputation (Low does not mean bad :) ) I could not accept the second answer! Also upvoting need 15+ reputation score.

Comment: @Achilles - no problem. I'm glad that you found my answer to be helpful.